# how does lxml speed up saving large excel file while using openpyxl?

Tags: python, lxml, openpyxl

I've some problem on saving large excel file while using openpyxl.
Openpyxl documentation says that

> When you want to dump large amounts of data make sure you have lxml installed.

But there is no code how to use openpyxl with lxml.
So it means I simply install lxml using pip?
Nothing to change code and this simple pip install speed up saving excel file?
Please answer me if you've experience.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you do not have to change any code, just install lxml.

Comment: Just only install lxml, it speeds up saving excel file?
How lxml affects to openpyxl

Comment: Apparently, `openpyxl` emulates `lxml` behaviour as a fallback if not installed. That's why you have to do nothing apart from installing it. That emulation is poor in efficiency.